# Where can I check the newest version NUMBER of constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-constraintlayout

I use constraing layout in my app.

However the layout editor pops me a warning that I use the obsolete library:

> Using version 1.0.0-alpha9 of the constraint library, which is
>   obsolete

In my gradle file I have:

```
com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9
```

Where can I check which one is the newest (up-to-date) version of this lib?

E D I T:

The question is about 'How do I know which version is the newest", not about updating the SDK to the newest (Because I still have to type a number which I do not know.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually Android Studio warns you about new updates by highlighting the line, then if you click on that line and press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> it will popup an option to update.

Or, you can look at this [instruction](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project) (the item #3), so you can see the latest version in your Android Studio SDK Manager Tools.

Or, you can also stay tuned about ConstraintLayout new updates in this link: http://tools.android.com/recent

Answer (score 1):

`alt` + `Enter` Shortcut for update.Also you can do from SDK Manager

[image]

Comment: so, how is this an answer to the question? on your screenshot version is missing for exactly what was asked

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check all versions even beta version and of course latest ones via
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

Google is offering libs over maven repos for CI systems.

For example, from there you can easily see that latest version of
constraint-layout is 1.1.0-beta3 under com.android.support.constraint
constraint-layout

Answer (score 0):

Open your SDK Manager in Android Studio. Then click on SDK Tools tab inside 'Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK. Under Support Repository, you can find ConstraintLayout for Android latest update about to download. Select and Apply changes.

Comment: Okay It is the updating procedure, but how do I know which version should I type in to gradle file? I have ran a version checker plugin and it says "Not found" for Latest Version.

Comment: compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta1'

Answer (score 0):

In the Android Studio, SDK Manager -> SDK Tools.

[SDK Manager location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ)

[ConstraintLayout in the Tools location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLPdb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the latest on maven repositiory. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.constraintlayout/constraintlayout